# How to create multiple recordsets for each selected checkbox

Tags: forms, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

i have the following schema and i want to create a Form with Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine where the user can choose an Magazine from a selectbox and then click several checkboxes, where each checkbox is one issue.

In pseudo markup it should look like this:

[select]Magazine[/select]

[checkbox]Issue 1[checkbox]

[checkbox]Issue 2[checkbox]

[checkbox]Issue 3[checkbox]

[checkbox]Issue 4[checkbox]

[checkbox]Issue 5[checkbox]

If the form is saved it should create one recordset for each checkbox selected. The advertisement ID is passed to the form via the url.

I tried several approaches to achieve this, but i stuck on this for several weeks now and hope someone here can help me.

In the real project i need a collection of 25 of the described forms, but this won't be a problem if i would only get this base form working.

Should i create a Advertisement form and embed the Planing form into it? I allways tried it direct with the Planing form.

Any suggestions, hint oder help is much appreciated.
And sorry for my poor english.

```
Advertisement:
  columns:
    title:                  { type: string(100), notnull: true }

Issue:
  columns:
    magazine_id:            { type: integer, notnull: true }
    number:                 { type: string(10), notnull: true }
  relations:
    Magazine:
      local: magazine_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: Issues
      type: one
      foreignType: many

Magazine:
  columns:
    title:                  { type: string(100) }

Planing:
  columns:
    advertisement_id:           { type: integer, notnull: true }
    magazine_id:                { type: integer, notnull: true }
    issue_id:                   { type: integer, notnull: true }
  relations:
    Issue:
      local: issue_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: Planings
      type: one
      foreignType: many
    Advertisement:
      local: advertisement_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: Planings
      type: one
      foreignType: many
    Magazine:
      local: magazine_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: Planings
      type: one
      foreignType: many
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly (let me check: you want to show an advertisement in certain issues of certain magazines?) then how about this?

Use a relation from the Planing object to the Issue object, one to many, and then use the built-in sfWidgetFormChoice as described on the Symfony blog here: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-1-2-make-your-choice (scroll down to "Group your Choices").

So instead of using sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice, use its parent and write your own method for building the array of issues, grouped by magazine, stored in a nested array. You can override the widget in your PlaningForm configuration like this:

```
$this->widgetSchema['issues_list'] = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
  'multiple' => true,
  'expanded' => true,
  'choices'  => Doctrine_Core::getTable('Issue')->getIssuesForSelect(),
));
```

Then add the method to `IssueTable.class.php` that returns a nested array of issue ids with titles, grouped by magazine title, which should look something like:

```
array(
  'Magazine 1' => array(
    17 => 'Issue 1',
    18 => 'Issue 2',
    28 => 'Issue 3',
  ),
  'Magazine 2' => array(
    11 => 'Issue 26',
    19 => 'Issue 27',
    29 => 'Issue 28',
  ),
);
```

Comment: I should add that this won't look quite like what you asked for (a select that changes checkboxes), but you can add that behaviour with javascript once the page has loaded.